# Private Message or substitute in Google+

Tags: google-plus

Is there any way to send a private message to one of your contacts? I saw, that we can share something with a single person and this "message" will either show up in the recipients *stream* (if he/she has added me to one of his/her circles) or in *incoming*, visible just for him/her and me.

Problem is - if my note goes to the stream and the others stream is update quite frequently (too-many-people-in-circles), then this private message will just get out of sight...

Anything I haven't discovered yet? Any rumors that private messages will be added to google+ during beta?

Answer (score 7):

Taken from here;

http://www.techradar.com/news/internet/web/20-google-tips-tricks-and-hints-978108

> You can send a message to just one person or a handful. Click in the Stream box and type your note. Now, remove the Public group by clicking the X. Add the names for those who will receive your note. Note that you can also type + and @ before a name to see a list of who to add.

Hope this helps.

Comment: That's exactly what I found out already (*can share something with a single person*) and those messages show up in the stream. I was looking for something else I might have missed. But thanks anyway!

Comment: Remember to disable re-sharing if your post is really private. You can do that after sending the message, by clicking on the small cirled arrow in the top right of the post.

Answer (score 4):

To allow people to send you a private message outside the Stream, go to your profile and hit the blue Edit Profile button.  Click on "Send an email" under your profile picture and this will pop up:

[image: Edit Profile]

If the box is checked then the "Send an email" button will be visible to the people you choose (Anyone on the web, Extended circles, Your circles, Only you, or Custom if you want to allow this for only certain circles or individuals).  If you choose "Anyone on the web", it will work for anyone logged in to a Google or Google Apps account (they do not need a Google+ profile).  When pressed, this little dialog will be shown where the user can enter a message:

[image: Send an email]

You will get the message in your email with their email address in the "From:" line, but they will not see your email address (unless you reply).  The message will indicate that it was sent from your Google profile.  They will also receive an email with a copy of the message text that they sent.

Note that the "Send an email" button won't work if you press it on your own profile.

Comment: Thanks! - I'll try that setting. Although I was hoping for some *facebookish* thing, a direct offline conversation within the webapp. But maybe I have to see all google webapps as a *whole* and gmail is *the* application for private messages..

Answer (score 2):

Except sharing a post with the person not really. The only possibility is to use the email address the user may provide (in the left column). I think Google still wants you to use email for private messaging (that's what Gmail is for actually and it works perfectly fine). I haven't found an instance where a Google spokesperson said something about private messaging.